# How does this queue implementation of Qemu work?

Tags: c, computer-science, singly-linked-list, qemu

I'm trying to understand Qemu's queue macros: https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/stable-4.2/include/qemu/queue.h

What does the following structures do?

```
typedef struct QTailQLink {
    void *tql_next;
    struct QTailQLink *tql_prev;
} QTailQLink;

/*
 * Tail queue definitions.  The union acts as a poor man template, as if
 * it were QTailQLink<type>.
 */
#define QTAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                                         \
union name {                                                            \
        struct type *tqh_first;       /* first element */               \
        QTailQLink tqh_circ;          /* link for circular backwards list */ \
}
```

ps: I found https://medium.com/@chenfelix/tail-queue-1b23232e4f49 but it's outdated, does not look like Qemu's source now.

Well, a Queue is a structure that stores some elements in an order, and you add on top of them:

> a queue is a collection of entities that are maintained in a sequence
> and can be modified by the addition of entities at one end of the
> sequence and the removal of entities from the other end of the
> sequence. Wikipedia

It makes sense to have a head for this queue, so I gues this is what the `QTAILQ_HEAD` does. You can hold a pointer to the first element. I wonder why not a pointer to the last also. Anyways, you can find the last by traversing the queue elements.

What does not make sense for me is the `QTailQLink tqh_circ;`. It's some recursive thing, but I don't understand why it's in the head.

Also, why such things exist: `QSLIST_INSERT_AFTER`, `QSLIST_INSERT_HEAD`? In a queue, by definition, you can only insert/remove at the tips. These macros make you insert at an arbitrary point.

Comment: *In a queue, by definition, you can only insert/remove at the tips.*. By who's definition? You are lining up in a queue to buy concert tickets but then you decide you've waited too long and want to leave. Do you have to wait til you get to the front to leave the queue? It makes sense that there is support for adding/removing from arbitrary locations in the queue even if that may not be the common operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment at the top of the header file defines what the properties of this data structure are:

```
 * A tail queue is headed by a pair of pointers, one to the head of the
 * list and the other to the tail of the list. The elements are doubly
 * linked so that an arbitrary element can be removed without a need to
 * traverse the list. New elements can be added to the list before or
 * after an existing element, at the head of the list, or at the end of
 * the list. A tail queue may be traversed in either direction.
```

Why this data structure and why these operations? Because it's a useful set of things to be able to do, and gives more flexibility than for a simple "all you can do is add at the tail and take off at the head" queue.

The header also notes that these macros are borrowed (and renamed) from those in the BSDs; you might want to read [the FreeBSD manpage on them](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=TAILQ_HEAD&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2B1.1.5.1-RELEASE) for some more detailed information.

More generally, almost nobody really needs to study the internals of these macros, except for educational purposes. If you're just writing QEMU code then you should be able to use the macros this header provides to do the operations like "traverse this queue" without having to care about how they are implemented internally.

If you do want to investigate how the macros are implemented, there are a couple of clever tricks that may be confusing you:

(1) Use of unions -- both the QTAILQ_HEAD() and QTAILQ_ENTRY() define unions, such that some of the fields are overlaid on top of each other, and the same pointer can be accessed in two ways. For instance in a QTAILQ_HEAD, the tqh_circ.tql_next pointer is the same as the qth_first pointer -- but one is a 'void *' and the other is a 'struct type *', so which one is used depends on whether the macro wants to effectively provide some type safety when it's doing an assignment to the pointer.

(2) A data item can be on more than one queue at once. This is done by having the data item's structure have multiple QTAILQ_ENTRY()s in its definition. This means the queue implementation needs to be careful about distinguishing "this is a pointer to a data item" from "this is a pointer to the QTailQLink embedded inside the data item" -- one data item structure could have several QTailQLinks, for different lists it could be on.

(3) Reusing the same data type in the head that is used in each data item (here, a QTailQLink) can be useful for avoiding having to special case "is this the first item in the list" in the various add/remove/etc operations. This is why it doesn't just use "prev pointer is NULL" for an empty queue.

(The header also defines a "simple queue" which is based on a singly linked list and avoids these clever tricks; it's less flexible and in some situations less efficient.)

My recommendation if you want to investigate further would be to draw out some diagrams of what exactly the data structure looks like, including which pointer fields point to which other places when you have a queue with, say, 3 entries in it.

Comment: @Paprika - this is an excellent response.  Please "upvote" and/or "accept" it if you found it helpful.  Moreover (as Peter Maydell suggests), quoting Linus Torvalds: ["Use the source, Luke"](https://wiki.c2.com/?UseTheSourceLuke)

Comment: A small addition: the main difference from the BSD version is that QEMU makes reverse iteration a bit easier to use thanks to the use of the "typeof" extension to C. Also, because QEMU uses typedefs liberally, QEMU doesn't care that QTAILQ is a union rather than a struct; doing that in BSD would be a bit jarring and require code changes everywhere. The tricks of the BSD implementation are not well documented, but you can find an explanation in the commit message that introduced QTailQLink (https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/qemu-devel/patch/20181217231700.24482-30-pbonzini@redhat.com/).

Answer (score 1):

1, This code implies that QTailQLink is a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list).  As such, we wouldn't necessarily need to save the tail - we can always find it by traversing from the head.

```
    typedef struct QTailQLink {
        void *tql_next;
        struct QTailQLink *tql_prev;
    } QTailQLink;
```

2. The meaning of QTAILQ_HEAD might be a bit clearer if you look at its companion macros in ["queue.h"](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/stable-4.2/include/qemu/queue.h):

   ```
    /*
     * Tail queue definitions.  The union acts as a poor man template, as if
     * it were QTailQLink<type>.
     */
    #define QTAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                                         \
    union name {                                                            \
        struct type *tqh_first;       /* first element */               \
        QTailQLink tqh_circ;          /* link for circular backwards list */ \
    }

    #define QTAILQ_HEAD_INITIALIZER(head)                                   \
        { .tqh_circ = { NULL, &(head).tqh_circ } }

    #define QTAILQ_ENTRY(type)                                              \
    union {                                                                 \
        struct type *tqe_next;        /* next element */                \
        QTailQLink tqe_circ;          /* link for circular backwards list */ \
    }
   ```

... and ...

```
/*
 * Tail queue functions.
 */
#define QTAILQ_INIT(head)
#define QTAILQ_INSERT_HEAD(head, elm, field)
#define QTAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(head, elm, field)
#define QTAILQ_INSERT_AFTER(head, listelm, elm, field)
#define QTAILQ_INSERT_BEFORE(listelm, elm, field)
#define QTAILQ_REMOVE(head, elm, field)
...
/*
 * Tail queue access methods.
 */
#define QTAILQ_EMPTY(head) 
#define QTAILQ_FIRST(head)  
#define QTAILQ_NEXT(elm, field)  
...
```

3. In other words, it's simply defining - and implementing - a bunch of standard queue operations with a linked list.